# How do I ignore comments in a text file with LabVIEW?

Tags: comments, labview

I've created a script file reader, nothing more than a glorified text reader that changes loop cases in my program, but I need it to be able to ignore comments on a line, execute that command, and go to the next line and process the new command after it finds the comment denoted with a semicolon. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.

Currently, the commands are read in like this:

```
 DO THIS FUNCTION
 DO THAT FUNCTION
```

I'd like to comment it with a semicolon like this:

```
DO THIS FUNCTION ;this is a comment to be ignored
```

Below is my text file read code, should be able to drag and drop it in to test. The command indicator just echoes the command being read. I've removed the rest of my program, sorry, can't send that part.

Can someone shed some light?

[image: Text File Reader]

Comment: Have you tried searching for a regular expression (like: `.*;` and removing the semicolon at the end) ?

Comment: @Moray I'm not sure how to parse the file looking for the semicolon and telling it to ignore everything after it, execute the current command, and advance to the next line. I'm not trying to remove the semicolon or anything from the text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is a semicolon used anywhere else in your file? Or is it just used to indicate a comment?

If it is only used to indicate a comment then as you read each line in, call the Split String primitive and split at the ";". Just use the top output regardless of whether or not the line contains a semicolon:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Does this function NEED to see the string split character? Or will it ignore it if it's not present?

Comment: You can read the information provided by NI. It tells you a lot about this funtion: 
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/search_split_string/

And if you are not sure after reading the information, you can just try it for yourself in a little test-vi. Just try different input-strings with the string you want to search. Wire some  indicators to the function and look what happens :)

Comment: @JediEngineer If the target char is not present, the entire original string comes out in the top output. That's what I was trying to say with the final sentence of my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Match Regular Expression Function" to split up the string, as @Moray already suggested.
Sadly I can't give you an example vi right now.

The main idea is:

- find the "Match Regular Expression Function"
- give it a ; as char to search for
- there are three outputs of the function (before match, match, after match)
- use the 'before match' instead of the whole line and give it to the rest of your program

This only works if your commands don't contain any ; except for the comments.

---

Note: I not quite sure what happens if you give the function a string that doesn't contain ; but you can figure that out by yourself by using the detailed help to this function :)